# Google Drive Rest API - Create File - Quota

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a program where I have to copy about 500,000 files onto google drive to different folders. I use the google drive v3 nodejs api. I issue about 2 uploads per second (every 450ms). After a while, I get ECONNRESET or  socket hang up from API.

When I look at the quota on the console.cloud.google.com. I am nowhere near my quota. Why is it failing?

For kicks, I have tried google filestream and it has no problems pushing into the drive under my user account. It's about 5 times faster.

Did anyone run into this problem?

Comment: is there an http error status? You're particularly looking for a 304 Rate Exceeded error

Comment: ECONNRESET:socket hang up is the error I get. I am familiar with the rate exceeded. I have a two stage process; one to create directories, the other to create the files. The first stage, I feed about 5 directories per second.. I'd get throttled back which I implemented the exponential backoff.. In this case, it is simply the above error...

Comment: understood. I have no idea. Heads up that exp backoff is far from an ideal algorithm to implement throttling. For max throughput you should implement adaptive backoff.

Answer (score 0):

I think your quota per se is not the problem here. This is happening when you're writing too much data within a short time frame. Try to slow it down and try to shard the requests across different user accounts. This should help with the heavy lifting of the many requests you are performing. Also, don't forget to implement [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#exponential-backoff) for 4xx error retries. My two cents.

Comment: The files are usually 2kb in size. It takes about a second to complete so I am trying to get a faster rate. Also the filemaker (google drive in its old incarnation) seems to do it a lot faster. When I drop it into the google drive folder, it took about 16 hours vs mine 4 days. That's the part that I cannot explain. I did implement exponential time off. However in some cases, it takes couple seconds for google to come back with a fail. So by the time google says no, I have already sent 10 files (3 files per second)... I throttle down for 10 seconds so in the end it turns to be serial

Answer (score 0):

This does happen when I call passing a stream. There is no warning in the developers.google.com but there is a warning at their [github repository](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client).

> You can also upload media by specifying media.body as a Readable stream. This can allow you to upload very large files that cannot fit into memory.
>
> Note: Your readable stream may be unstable. Use at your own risk.

Once I have changed it not to use the streams, I started getting the proper error message such as status code 403, going over your rate limit.

I simply changed my code to use a straight buffer. Buffer is read via fs.readFileSync before the call.

```
media: {
  mimeType: 'text/plain',
  body: buf
}
```

Comment: Now that I read my question, I can see this is a partial answer. I am still not clear why google comes back with 403 even though I am not over the quota. I am guessing I am hitting an internal undisclosed limit when uploading the file.